# How to change the order of the % symbol and text in PHP block

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm customizing a WordPress theme, and there's a specific piece of code in a specific file that, on the website, shows a number in percentile, like %60, or %30.

What I want to do is have the % sign and number switched around, so it shows 30% instead.

The entire block of code responsible for the number and percent sign is below, but it's this specific bit that does it.

```
{ echo _e('%', 'trek') . $deposit;}?>
```

I've tried moving the bits around in various iterations, but clearly the answer is more complex than that. The entire block of code is below.

How would I alter the code to display the result, 30%, instead of the %30 it currently displays?

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php $deposit = get_post_meta($postid, "tk_tour_deposit", true); ?>

<tr><td><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></td><td><h5><?php if(get_post_meta($postid, "tk_tour_deposit", true) ) { echo _e('%', 'trek') . $deposit;}?></h5></td><td><a class="btn btn-small" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('+ information', 'trek'); ?></a></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$deposit` is the amount? Can't you just swap it with the symbol, like so:

Change:

```
echo _e('%', 'trek') . $deposit;
```

To:

```
echo $deposit . _e('%', 'trek');
```

Edit:

I know what the problem is. According to the [Wordpress function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) `_e` echos directly rather than returning a value, so you should be doing this:

```
echo $deposit; _e('%', 'trek');
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but for whatever reason, it's not changing the order of items when I do that.

Comment: Is it being cached by any chance?

Comment: Cleared my cache, checked on another machine

Comment: I meant severside caching.

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent any changes from being seen? That's not the case, in other tests, the % and $deposit amount disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple regex

```
echo preg_replace('#%([0-9]+)#', '$1%', $deposit);
```

or substr() depends what you want

```
echo substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-1).'%';
```

or to better visiblity you could try to use this example:

```
printf('%d %s', $deposit, _e('%', 'trek'));
```

Comment: Thanks, using a combination of the first and second lines did the trick.

Comment: This is just silly! The percentage symbol is clearly not in `$deposit`.

Comment: clearly I don't know what is content of $deposit variable

Comment: But you can see the percentage symbol is being passed the the `_e()` function in the same `echo` statement. Everything you need to know is there.